# Can't connect Visual Studio to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

I use Visual Studio 2017, I connected to my database from Server Explorer:

[image: here it is].

Then I added SQL connection:

```
var constring = @"Data Source=JSINJARA\SQLEXPRESS,Database=box,Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
```

But when I try to open connection I get the following exception:

[image: exception]

What can be the problem?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages. Post it as text, please.

Comment: Use `;` (semicolon) instead of `,` (comma) in the connection string. See the [Connection Strings website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for many examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `;` (semicolon) instead of `,` (comma) in the connection string.

E.g.

```
var constring = @"Data Source=JSINJARA\SQLEXPRESS;Database=box;Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
```

See the [Connection Strings website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for many examples.

Answer (score 2):

Better add it to [app/web].config file and get it using `ConfigurationManager`.
It's should look something like this:

### Config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=<<Server>>;Initial Catalog=<<DBName>>;User=<<User>>;Password=<<Password>>;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

### C#:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Integrated Security=True` in connection